# AWS CloudFront with API Gateway getting error missing authentication token

Tags: aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudfront

I've configured CloudFront to S3 with a static page and the second behavior on API Gateway with a simple API. The static page works fine but I have a problem with API Gateway because when I try to send a request to API then I got an error 'missing authentication token'. I've configured allowed headers but still, I get this error. API Gateway connects with AWS lambda.

I want to have  on / simple static page but on  /somePath path API which handles a request from static page.

Have you some ideas about what exactly can be wrong?

Comment: Are you able to hit the API endpoint directly without any issues? Missing Authentication Token is also an indication that the URL being used to invoke the API is not in the right format.

Comment: Yes I do. API gateway works fine but I tried to used proxy on API gateway and currently I got a 502 error. I tired to setup with mock but still it doesn’t work..

Comment: For the 502, did you check API Gateway execution logs? That will give you a more specific error message

Comment: 502 is was bad configured API Gateway but I found the reason..I did the exercise and I redirect CloudFront to API Gateway without S3 and on the default path (in cache behavior section) and API Gateway works correctly, but when I tried to set S3 on default path and API Gateway on /api path I got a error "Missing Authentication Token".

Answer (score 0):

> "Maybe is a problem with my approach because I want to have on / path static page application but on path /api API Gateway application. The routing between S3 and API gateway is realised via CloudFront and CloudFront can not connect with API gateway, I mean when I call GET method then I got a error."

I recently presented the same situation. I was getting a 403 error with a missing authentication token message. Also, the X-Cache header response was "Error from cloudfront" (Which obviously was not too helpful). After some digging and too many logs activations I found that my **route in the apiGateway has to match with the behavior Path pattern at the route path**. Example:

I had an API Gateway configured like this:

[image]

"At first instance, I was assuming that API Gateway would recognize the path pattern, sent by Cloudfront if I requested GET to: https://<stage>.<domain>.com/api/resource (cloudfront url)", but here is the catch when I was logging the API Gateway requests, for debugging purposes, I found that **API Gateway requests were trying to fall at "/api/resource" path. Instead of "/resources"**. Even when I had configured the behavior path to send it through the /resources path it was arriving to API gateway like: "/stage/api/resources".Therefore you need to do this steps:

1. **Change the path on your API gateway to match with your cloudfront behaviour  distribution**. I would recommend using the path /api/resource but is up to you (On my example I left it like it was to explain what you need to do)

[image]

2. (Needed If you didn't change the path to use "/api/")Add two path patters in the origin if you haven't - Those will match with your API Gateway. Note: *In case you created the /api in your API Gateway you will only require the api/**
   [image]
3. Make sure you have configured Cloudfront origin domain properly
   [image]
4. (Optional but recommended) Add the x-api-key auth to **your origin** config
   [image]
5. After doing the config, just wait like 5 minutes and try to test it
   [image]

This is possible, but I recommend you standardize it a little bit so your API Gateway gets a better structure. This will help to avoid some CORS issues! And also makes your API be handled by CloudFront (If you have configured your API gateway with proper restrictions).  So enjoy it!

Answer (score -2):

In your API Gateway Resources page, is "API Key Required" set to true for the endpoints you are trying to hit? To check, go to the "Resources" page, select the endpoint you are checking by clicking on the method (ie. GET), then clicking "Method Request". If it is, you need to pass in x-api-key in the header.

Comment: Missing authentication token could be multiple reasons, not necessarily related to API key.

Comment: That's true. If you look at the response header it actually tells you the error.

Comment: API Key is not required, but I think there is a problem with response from lambda to API Gateway, maybe some headers are returning and CloudFront doesn't accept this.

Comment: Maybe is a problem with my approach because I want to have on /  path static page application but on path /api API Gateway application. The routing between S3 and API gateway is realised via CloudFront and CloudFront can not connect with API gateway, I mean when I call GET method then I got a error..